# How Do I Connect HTML to CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am relatively new to CSS and HTML, but I just had a tutorial on connecting HTML documents to CSS sheets. It didn't work, and I have searched everywhere for the answer. All the sites had feasible answers, but none worked for mine.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title>FlyHighGames|Home</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> <!--Bro what does this even mean?-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help!

Comment: Your HTML looks fine.  Where is your CSS, and what does that look like?

Comment: Your code is okay.

Comment: let the 'stylesheet.css' file on the same folder of this html page.

Comment: `stylesheet.css` in same folder where your html file located?

Comment: The line `<meta charset="utf-8">` means that on PC's that don't use English encoding, this content will render fine; otherwise it'll look garbled. The UTF-8 encoding supports most languages.

Comment: 'stylesheet' is on the same folder that HTML is located, so the problem is wierd.

Answer (score 1):

use folder name if you saving css in any folder

```
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="foldername/stylesheet.css"/>
```

Comment: `type="text/css"` is not necessary with HTML5. Neither is the self-closing character at the end .css `/`>

Comment: right. but he is new with css. he dont know basic css

Comment: i change it now you happy :)

Comment: Yes. Thank you. But, you do still have the self-termination character at the end.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you need to use the link element:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="pathToCSSFile">
```

FYI the: `type="text/css"` part is no longer needed in HTML5

> But, to correctly indicate the path to the .css file, follow these
>   rules:

1. If the resource you need is part of the same web site (not talking about folder structure here, talking about domain), you should use relative paths, where:

   a. **fileName.ext** is all you need if the resource is in the same folder as the currently loaded document.

   b. **folderName/fileName.ext** is what you need if the file you need is in a sub-folder of the current folder that the loaded document is in.

   c. **../fileName.ext** is what to use if the file you need is one directory higher than the current document's folder. The `../` can be repeated if you need to go up more than one level (i.e. **`../../fileName.ext`**).

   d. **/fileNameext** or **/folderName/fileName.ext** indicates that the file or folder specified should be found starting from the root of the web site, regardless of where the current document is.
2. If the resource you need is located on another domain, you'd use an **Absolute Path** (http://something.something/file.ext).

   a. DO NOT use absolute paths for local resources!  This may work but causes the domain name to have to be resolved again, resulting in a longer load time.

**WARNING**: Different servers have different configurations and requirements that may affect whether these reference rules work or not. For example, GoDaddy web hosting provides an "httpDocs" folder at the root of a web site. You don't have to use it, but that's where their servers expect the site's content to be placed. Not following those rules result in relative paths not working.

**NOTES**:

1. If you feel that you've referenced the CSS file correctly, you may have a syntax error in that file which is preventing the CSS from being processed. You can run your CSS through a validator (https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to see if it's valid.
2. You can also hit the `F12` key with your web page open and click on the Network tab and refresh the page. This will show you all the network requests made by the current page. If you see the CSS file listed and then see a 404 message next to it, you know the file wasn't found.

Comment: I pressed f12 and did what you said, but it said that "It was not allowed to use a local resource" and then the path to my css file...?

Comment: @GeraldMoore Ok, well I think we're on to something here. Are you running this code from a web server or are you testing right off your file system?

Answer (score 0):

The link tag is used to link to external style sheets. check your css file path  try this code work fine

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
```

you need to attech style sheet beetween head tag.

Comment: `type="text/css"` is not necessary with HTML5

Comment: Specifies the media type of the linked document

Comment: And, it's not needed any more for CSS links.

Answer (score 0):

As other said, use the link tag, but I sometimes get an error, if I add a slash at the end as required in XHTML as it automatically closes the tag and doesn't allow it to access other parts of the page.

Comment: Including the self-termination character will not affect whether you link to the CSS file correctly. It will only make the markup valid as XHTML - IF that is even desired.

Comment: exactly @Scott Marcus, you just said what I wanted to say. Thanks!

Comment: No, not really. In HTML5 having the character or not having it makes no difference. And, frankly even in HTML4 it wouldn't either. It would never disallow access to the rest of the page. The only benefit is that is makes your code valid to an XML parser.

Comment: It does, atleast when I'm using it

Comment: You'd have to show me that, because and HTML parser ignores what it doesn't understand. It will understand `<link rel="" href=""` and when it gets to the `/`, it will just ignore it and move on. Really,

Answer (score -1):

Create a css stylesheet.css file and save in folder where HTML file exits

Answer (score -2):

Provide complete path of your stylesheet file
example

```
<link href="Content/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: How do you know this path. `Content/css/stylesheet.css` ?

Comment: The path is related to where your .html file is located. In example, if your index.html file is in the `Content` folder, you should use `css/stylesheet.css` as a path.

Comment: its a fake path just for your reference. where have you placed your stylesheet?

Comment: Why the assumption that the `stylesheet.css` is in a folder called Content? Not mentioned by the OP either.

Comment: this is not an aassumption. Its an example it could be any folder